# Why can't get the length of the pdf file with `CURLINFO_CONTENT_LENGTH_DOWNLOAD` in php_curl?

Tags: php, pdf, curl, dropbox

I have to get filesize of a remote  file by using curl in PHP
the file is hosted on Dropbox which  will be downloaded by direct link
below is my code what I have written

```
$szUrl='https://www.dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/8ol4o753smure2o/Holy_Quran_in_Turkish.pdf';
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_exec($curl);


    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $szUrl);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);


   $size = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_CONTENT_LENGTH_DOWNLOAD);
  echo $size;

curl_close($curl);
```

The output is -1 with the code, How to get the length of the iso file properly with php_curl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the curl options before you exec:

```
<?php

   $szUrl='https://www.dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/8ol4o753smure2o/Holy_Quran_in_Turkish.pdf';
   $curl = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $szUrl);
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1);
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
   curl_exec($curl);
   $size = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_CONTENT_LENGTH_DOWNLOAD);
   echo $size;
   curl_close($curl);
```

Comment: however, it works perfectly on localhost but not live server,